# Google+ Business account, adding scripts to automatically add co-workers to a new users co-worker circle

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am completely new to Google Scripts and Google+ for that matter (C# MVC / JavaScript dev). I have been asked to investigate automatically adding all members of staff' Google+ User account to a circle, named 'co-worker' for any new starter's Google+ profile.

1)  Generate Enumerable of all employees.
2)  Create new circle ‘co-worker’ for a new user added to the business account.
3)  Add all users in step 1 to the new user’s, newly created ‘co-worker’ circle.
4)  Automate the process to occur when a new user is added for the first time or logs in         for the first time.

it would be great if you could give me some grounding on terms i.e. what am I looking to build here is it a Google Scripts App Gadget for the Business App, is there API tutorials out there?

any information for me to get my head into the task really would be great.

TIA.

[EDIT] Ignore step 2 I have just realised that Google+ has that by default.

Comment: Updated my answer, which I believe now is addressed with the new API release.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited 8/14/2013*

The [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) offers you this functionality for Google Apps domains. You can [manage circles](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/circles/). From what you're proposing though, I believe you'd need to use the Directory API within the Admin SDK to get a [list of all of your domain users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users).

One issue that you might have, is that you can't manage circles or make posts on behalf of a user until they have activated their Google+ profile for their Google Apps account, which requires the user to accept the terms. Until then you would get `invalid_request` errors.